# Passing a element value and an array in ajax to a PHP page

Tags: php, ajax

I'm building an array like this:

```
$('.el').each(function(e) {
    arr.push({
        date: $(this).data('date'),
        roomid : $(this).data('roomid'),
        status : $(this).data('status')
    });
});
```

I'm passing at the final an array like this:

```
[{date: "2019-05-01", roomid: 107, status: "Close"}, {date: "2019-05-02", roomid: 107, status: "Close"}]
```

After I'm passing this array to my PHP script like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { datas : arr },
    url  : url
...
```

How can I transform my code to include into the `data` a new element where:

```
var return_url = 'welcome';
```

Can I make this:

```
data: { return_url=welcome, datas : arr },
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to write the data in valid JavaScript object format:

```
data : { return_url : "welcome", datas : arr }
```

or if you use a var for the URL then use:

```
var return_url = 'welcome';
data : { return_url : return_url, datas : arr }
```